# Add a tabpage from another tabpage in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tabpage

I am trying to add a new `tabpage` to a `tabcontrol` by clicking a `data-grid` view in another `tabpage` of the same form. 
using the fallowing code for the task but not getting any error or output.

```
Dim TP As New TabPage
TP.Text = "   Payment    . "
form1.TabControlEx1.TabPages.Add(TP)
form1.TabControlEx1.SelectedTab = TP
Dim child As New FastPayment
child.TopLevel = False 
child.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
child.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
TP.Controls.Add(child)
child.Show()
```

Comment: My guess is `FastPayment` is a `Form` and if that's the case that's your problem. You cant add a `Form` to a `TabPage` that is what user controls are for... If you want to add a `Form` the hosting control needs to be an MDI container and use `ShowDialog`...

Comment: Add form1.Show().  If you now see another window, otherwise dead to the world, then pay attention to Steve's comment.  Displaying UI in a worker thread is a very bad idea.

Comment: Hans Passant 
i dont want to add a new form , i just want to add a new tab to the form1 , form 1 is a parent form where tabcontrol is present and in that tabcontrols i am opening the other forms like payment , receipt and all.

Comment: we can easily add a form to a tabpage Why are you saying we cant add a form to a tabpage ?... zaggler